# What is the correct way of embedding tweets using twitter api

Tags: javascript, api, twitter

I am working on a website where I want to show the most recent 3 tweets from my Twitter profile. There is a way to embed the tweets by using the publish.twitter.com URL, the problem with this method is that I cannot style my embedded tweets and it doesn't even show the number of likes and retweets. I want to get the recent tweets using the Twitter API where I am in control of the embedded tweets and can style them.
here is what I am using to embed tweets on my website.

```
<div class="twitter-feed" style="display:flex; align-items:center; justify-content:center;">
     <a class="twitter-timeline" href="https://twitter.com/dev_taimoor?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw">Tweets by dev_taimoor</a> <script async src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</div>
```

I need to know a way of using Twitter API through javascript so that I can fetch tweets. I did some research but none of the articles were helpful for me.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked @Jason_mayes Twitter fetcher https://codepen.io/jasonmayes/pen/ndWRdd
`see code above`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).